# Is there a feature in VIsual Studio or Resharper that can extract XAML into a separate file?

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, resharper

In ASP.NET Forms and MVC, you can select a block of code and extract it into a separate user control or file using Resharper and possibly Visual Studio. I cannot find such a feature for XAML. Does it exist in either Resharper or Visual Studio? If so, how do you perform this action?

Answer (score -2):

I think you are looking for this:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/ReSharper_by_Language__XAML__Refactorings.html
Resharper allows you to extract styles and resources, but you have to select the XAML and go to Resharper->Refactor->Extract in order to find the options, you won't see them if you use ALT+ENTER.

Comment: I was looking for something that extracts XAML markup rather than just the styles and resources.  Ideally, I should be able to select a tag and all its children and move it to a separate file.